# Problems with DB linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

My db link on DEV environment is working fine.
But for the test I have windows without a GUI environment. With the help of my colleagues, I managed to set it up precisely like on DEV.

The DB link works but when it is called from the application, I still get the error ""The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "DB Linked SERVER" was unable to begin a distributed transaction. [Failed SQL: (7391) INSERT INTO table""

I set the necessary ones in component services and on the db link
[image: DTC][image: DB link properties]

On local DTC properties, I got ALLOW REMOTE CONNECTIONS CHECKED
Don't know where the error could be?
It runs under a user that is set as **sysadmin**.

Comment: Which server did you set those DTC properties on, the local server or the remote server? What is the query you're trying to run? What version of SQL Server are both servers running?

Comment: I set these DTC properties on both servers. The question is about creating a table.

Comment: "*The question is about creating a table.*"' - Surely you're running a remote query otherwise you wouldn't be receiving the type of error you are. So regardless of how simple that query is, it would be helpful for you to add the exact code of it. Also: "*What version of SQL Server are both servers running?*'

Comment: Creating a table with a very simple create table code.
CREATE TABLE MY TABLE.
There may be a mistake in the second question, but I'm not sure.
One instance runs SQL server 2019 and the other runs SQL server 2022.

Comment: "*Creating a table with a very simple create table code. CREATE TABLE MY TABLE*" - I have a feeling this isn't the problematic query unfortunately, because it doesn't seem to involve a remote query, and the error you provided in the Post mentions "*Failed SQL: (7391) INSERT INTO table*". Are you creating a table and then subsequently trying to insert into it remotely?